# Erro ao criar o bean com o nome 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Estou tentado utilizar o Spring Security, mas está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

> GRAVE: Exceção ao enviar evento de contexto iniciado para instância listener da classe [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@6ef11a53 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:601)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1113)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4666)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>           at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>           at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@6ef11a53 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:590)
>           ... 46 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@6ef11a53 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:63)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$CompositeObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:117)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:77)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:32)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:37)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:376)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:238)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:178)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7135bcec.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$6()
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7135bcec$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9a39d586.invoke()
>           at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>           at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7135bcec.springSecurityFilterChain()
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
>           ... 47 more
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@6ef11a53': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
>           at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:60)
>           ... 73 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
>           at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
>           at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:94)
>           at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
>           ... 75 more

**Arquivo pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.casadocodigo</groupId>
  <artifactId>casadocodigo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <finalName>casadocodigo</finalName>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion> 
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.15</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- s3ninja -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.scireum</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3ninja</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.133</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <!-- Jackson é um biblioteca para transformar objetos em JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>        
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cache -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>SPring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestones/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project

>
```

Comment: Parece que você não informou nenhuma implementação do `UserDetailsService`, você já criou sua implementação?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar um service que implemente UserDetailsService.

Por exemplo:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {
    private User user;

    public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    //...
}
```

Devido a anotação `@Service` a aplicação vai detectar UserDetailsService durante o component-scan.